How do I insert a new Theme.css into my app?
The old css file in my app failed, and I would get a compliance check failed error every time I started the Simulator. I copied the changes I made to the old .css into a Word doc, deleted the "damaged" .css, created a new Theme.css in the CSS folder, and started added each mod back in. The changes did not show up in my app, so I found my last test frame I created  in the Initializer, copied and added the code to set the UIManager ( shown below ). The app rebuilds with no errors, but when I Run I get a NullPointerException, telling me the theme.res is not found in the .jar (Library). Is there a way to get the app to accept the new Theme.css, or do I need to build a new frame and add the old class code to new classes?
    private Resources theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/Theme.css");


Isn't theme in lower case? This is case sensitive. Look in the target directory during the build, you should see a .res file e.g. for this you should see Theme.css.res.
